# Can you add any request header when you request from a webpage?

Tags: http, url, service, header

Also, can you SEND any header back? (return headers) when you run a web server?

Or, are headers limited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web pages are retrieved using the HTTP protocol. HTTP is text-based. Both, a client requesting and a server responding within a HTTP communication can add custom headers to the HTTP messages. Its up to the communicating parties how to process these. I would assume that an unknown header is dropped silently.

Comment: From what I've seen, the prefix "x-" is generally how client/server add non-standard headers in their responses.